# How to load CPU microcode in Debian?

Tags: debian, cpu, firmware

How do you do that, e.g. for `microcode_amd_fam15h.bin`?

What is in `/lib/firmware/amd-ucode`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should install the `amd64-microcode` package using the package manager.

It will provide the `/lib/firmware/amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam15h.bin` file for you (and also other microcode files for other AMD processor families).

It will also provide the script `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64_microcode`, which will run as part of any `update-initramfs -u` operation, to add the microcode and the procedure to feed it into the CPU as early in the boot process as possible. Installing the `amd64-microcode` package will probably run `update-initramfs -u` for you automatically.

If you need more information, you might want to read the files in `/usr/share/doc/amd64-microcode/` (after installing the `amd64-microcode` package). [Here's a web copy of the main README file as it currently exists on the stable Debian 11.](https://sources.debian.org/src/amd64-microcode/3.20191218.1/debian/README.Debian/)

If you need to use a different version of the microcode for any reason (e.g. you have a problem and need to verify with an older microcode, or have a newer microcode and the Debian package has not yet been updated), you should just overwrite the packaged `/lib/firmware/amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam15h.bin` with the desired microcode version, run `update-initramfs -u` and then reboot.